# Function or other basic script that compares values on two variables in a dataframe using an id variable located in both

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

Let's say you have two data frames, both of which contain some, but not all of the same records. Where they are the same records, the id variable in both data frames matches. There is a particular variable in each data frame that needs to be checked for consistency across the data frames, and any discrepancies need to be printed:

```
d1 <- ## first dataframe
d2 <- ## second dataframe

colnames(d1) #column headings for dataframe 1
[1] "id" "variable1" "variable2" "variable3"

colnames(d2) #column headings for dataframe 2 are identical
[1] "id" "variable1" "variable2" "variable3"

length(d1$id) #there are 200 records in dataframe 1
[1] 200

length(d2$id) #there are not the same number in dataframe 2
[1] 150

##Some function that takes d1$id, matches with d2$id, then compares the values of the matched, returning any discrepancies
```

I constructed an elaborate loop for this, but feel as though this is not the right way of going about it. Surely there is some better way than this for-if-for-if-if statement.

```
for (i in seq(d1$id)){ ##Sets up counter for loop
  if (d1$id[i] %in% d2$id){ ## Search, compares and saves a common id and variable
    index <- d1$id[i];
    variable_d1 <- d1$variable1[i];
    for (p in seq(d2$id)){ set
      if (d2$id[p] == index){ ## saves the corresponding value in the second dataframe
        variable_d2 <- d2$variable1[p];
          if (variable_d2 != variable_d1) { ## prints if they are not equal
            print(index);
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want a database join, probably you can use left_join from dplyr, but you should give us sample data and output in a reproducible manner first.

Comment: @AlexanderOrona, Minor point: you should use `seq_along()` instead of `seq()` when generating a sequence along a vector. This is because if the input vector happens to contain only one element, `seq()` changes its behavior to generate a sequence from 1 to the value of the element. So, for example, `seq(3)` generates `1 2 3`, but you would want `1` here. Alternatively, you can use `1:length(x)`, but that won't correctly handle the degenerate case of a zero-length vector. `seq_along()` handles all these cases perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, using random input data with a 50% chance that a given cell will be discrepant between `d1` and `d2`:

```
set.seed(1);
d1 <- data.frame(id=sample(300,200),variable1=sample(2,200,replace=T),variable2=sample(2,200,replace=T),variable3=sample(2,200,replace=T));
d2 <- data.frame(id=sample(300,150),variable1=sample(2,150,replace=T),variable2=sample(2,150,replace=T),variable3=sample(2,150,replace=T));
head(d1);
##    id variable1 variable2 variable3
## 1  80         1         2         2
## 2 112         1         1         2
## 3 171         2         2         1
## 4 270         1         2         2
## 5  60         1         2         2
## 6 266         2         2         2
head(d2);
##    id variable1 variable2 variable3
## 1 258         1         2         1
## 2  11         1         1         1
## 3 290         2         1         2
## 4 222         2         1         2
## 5  81         2         1         1
## 6 200         1         2         1
com <- intersect(d1$id,d2$id); ## derive common id values
d1com <- match(com,d1$id); ## find indexes of d1 that correspond to common id values, in order of com
d2com <- match(com,d2$id); ## find indexes of d2 that correspond to common id values, in order of com
v1diff <- com[d1$variable1[d1com]!=d2$variable1[d2com]]; ## get ids of variable1 discrepancies
v1diff;
##  [1]  60 278  18 219 290  35 107   4 237 131  50 210  29 168   6 174  61 127  99 220 247 244 157  51  84 122 196 125 265 115 186 139   3 132 223 211 268 102 155 207 238  41 199 200 231 236 172 275 250 176 248 255 222  59 100  33 124
v2diff <- com[d1$variable2[d1com]!=d2$variable2[d2com]]; ## get ids of variable2 discrepancies
v2diff;
##  [1] 112  60  18 198 219 290 131  50 210  29 168 258 215 291 127 161  99 220 110 293  87 164  84 122 196 125 186 139  81 132  82  89 223 268  98  14 155 241 207 231 172  62 275 176 248 255  59 298 100  12 156
v3diff <- com[d1$variable3[d1com]!=d2$variable3[d2com]]; ## get ids of variable3 discrepancies
v3diff;
##  [1] 278 219 290  35   4 237 131 168 202 174 215 220 247 244 261 293 164  13 294  84 196 125 265 115 186  81   3  89 223 211 268  98  14 155 241 207  38 191 200 276 250  45 269 255 298 100  12 156 124
```

Here's a proof that all `variable1` values for ids in `v1diff` are really discrepant between `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1$variable1[match(v1diff,d1$id)]; d2$variable1[match(v1diff,d2$id)];
##  [1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
##  [1] 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2
```

Here's a proof that all `variable1` values for ids *not* in `v1diff` are *not* discrepant between `d1` and `d2`:

```
with(subset(d1,id%in%com&!id%in%v1diff),variable1[order(id)]); with(subset(d2,id%in%com&!id%in%v1diff),variable1[order(id)]);
##  [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
##  [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
```

Here, I wrapped this solution in a function which returns the vectors of discrepant id values in a list, with each component named for the variable it represents:

```
compare <- function(d1,d2,cols=setdiff(intersect(colnames(d1),colnames(d2)),'id')) {
    com <- intersect(d1$id,d2$id);
    d1com <- match(com,d1$id);
    d2com <- match(com,d2$id);
    setNames(lapply(cols,function(col) com[d1[[col]][d1com]!=d2[[col]][d2com]]),cols);
};
compare(d1,d2);
## $variable1
##  [1]  60 278  18 219 290  35 107   4 237 131  50 210  29 168   6 174  61 127  99 220 247 244 157  51  84 122 196 125 265 115 186 139   3 132 223 211 268 102 155 207 238  41 199 200 231 236 172 275 250 176 248 255 222  59 100  33 124
##
## $variable2
##  [1] 112  60  18 198 219 290 131  50 210  29 168 258 215 291 127 161  99 220 110 293  87 164  84 122 196 125 186 139  81 132  82  89 223 268  98  14 155 241 207 231 172  62 275 176 248 255  59 298 100  12 156
##
## $variable3
##  [1] 278 219 290  35   4 237 131 168 202 174 215 220 247 244 261 293 164  13 294  84 196 125 265 115 186  81   3  89 223 211 268  98  14 155 241 207  38 191 200 276 250  45 269 255 298 100  12 156 124
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `merge`.

First, merge the dataframes, keeping all columns.

```
x <- merge(d1, d1, by="id")
```

Then, find all rows which do not match:

```
x[x$variable1.x != x$variable1.y | x$variable2.x != x$variable2.y | 
  x$variable3.x != x$variable3.y, ]
```